# How to add categorical layered data to LayerControl() in python Folium map?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I have this categorical dataset in which I will like each category/group to be a layer I can turn ON/OFF.

Am able to add the groups on 'LayerControl', but it doesn't work properly as expected.

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[39.712183, -104.998424], zoom_start=5)

data = [(36.314292, -117.517516, 'P1'),
             (40.94859, -116.15316, 'P2'),
             (34.14757, -119.81985, 'P3'),
             (46.31292, -117.57516, 'P4'),
             (41.04159, -116.15316, 'P2'),
             (44.22093, -119.821985,'P2'), 
             (42.25308, -117.27589, 'P3'),
             (41.60302, -115.97012, 'P4'),
             (44.35519, -117.94183, 'P4'),
             (44.02027, -117.22198, 'P1'),
             (45.91613, -113.05364, 'P5'),
             (48.17537, -117.90075, 'P1'),
             (37.65961, -117.61321, 'P1')]


for x in range(0, len(data)):
    
    point_layer = folium.FeatureGroup(name = latLong[x][2])

    for lat,lng,nameP in latLong:
        point_layer.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lat, lng], radius=10,
            popup=str(nameP) + " Lat: " + str(lat) + " , Long: " + str(lng), 
            tooltip=str(nameP) + " Lat: " + str(lat) + " , Long: " + str(lng),
            fill=True,  # Set fill to True
            color='red',
            fill_opacity=1.0)).add_to(m)

    
    m.add_child(point_layer)


m.add_child(folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False))  
m.save("Map1.html")
```

[image]

As you see from above, the buttons are off yet the points/circles still display on the map. Any idea to fixing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To associate a marker with a layer, create a point group and set the marker to belong to it. You can then add the point group to the map. The code in the question creates a point group in a loop process, but we can change the process to create a point group in advance and then add it to the map.

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[39.712183, -104.998424], zoom_start=5)

latLong = [(36.314292, -117.517516, 'P1'),
             (40.94859, -116.15316, 'P2'),
             (34.14757, -119.81985, 'P3'),
             (46.31292, -117.57516, 'P4'),
             (41.04159, -116.15316, 'P2'),
             (44.22093, -119.821985,'P2'), 
             (42.25308, -117.27589, 'P3'),
             (41.60302, -115.97012, 'P4'),
             (44.35519, -117.94183, 'P4'),
             (44.02027, -117.22198, 'P1'),
             (45.91613, -113.05364, 'P5'),
             (48.17537, -117.90075, 'P1'),
             (37.65961, -117.61321, 'P1')]

# point_layer name list
all_gp = []
for x in range(len(latLong)):
    pg = latLong[x][2]
    all_gp.append(pg)

# Create point_layer object
unique_gp = list(set(all_gp))
vlist = []
for i,k in enumerate(unique_gp):
    locals()[f'point_layer{i}'] = folium.FeatureGroup(name=k)
    vlist.append(locals()[f'point_layer{i}'])

# Creating list for point_layer
pl_group = []
for n in all_gp:
    for v in vlist: 
        if n == vars(v)['layer_name']:
            pl_group.append(v)

for (lat,lng,nameP),pg in zip(latLong, pl_group):
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[lat, lng], radius=10,
        popup=str(nameP) + " Lat: " + str(lat) + " , Long: " + str(lng), 
        tooltip=str(nameP) + " Lat: " + str(lat) + " , Long: " + str(lng),
        fill=True,  # Set fill to True
        color='red',
        fill_opacity=1.0).add_to(pg)
    pg.add_to(m)

m.add_child(folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False))  
#m.save("Map1.html")
m
```

[image]

Comment: This is getting close, thank you. However, I see problem when a new point group is add (lets say P6) it means FeatureGroup and pl_group will have to be manually set. I did love if it made dynamic to accept arbitrary point groups/layers?

Comment: This is the answer to your question about how to group markers and associate them with layers. Dealing with the addition of new groups is the domain of Python, not folium. Was this included in your question? It is possible to create local variables in loop processing.

Comment: Fixed so that when a new point group is added, it will automatically be created and associated with the group without having to be manually modified. Please check.