# Folium MarkerCluster and Layers merging Clusters

Tags: python, layer, folium, markerclusterer

I'm currently working on a map of supermarkets in the Netherlands and have different Layers for each supermarket as shown in the first picture. However for each layer there is a cluster on the map and these are not merged together as larger clusters. I would like to have the layer controls as in the first picture and the clustering of the second picture. To achieve this I'm using the code from [Folium put markers in marker clusters AND in layers based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222835/folium-put-markers-in-marker-clusters-and-in-layers-based-on-a-value) of the user r-beginners.  What's the right way to have the best of both worlds?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

stores = [(-23.5578906,-46.6665546, 'store1','ALDI'),
             (-23.562711,-46.674363, 'store2','LIDL'),
             (-23.5642399,-46.6681833, 'store3','ALDI'),
             (-23.584167,-46.678497, 'store4','LIDL'),
             (-23.5956238,-46.6865377, 'store5','ALDI'),
             (-23.5868682,-46.6773554,'store6','LIDL'), 
             (-23.6011096,-46.6739275, 'store7','ALDI'),
             (-23.6087354,-46.6973713, 'store8','LIDL'),
             (-23.5943515,-46.6846959, 'store9','ALDI')]

df = pd.DataFrame(stores, columns=['LAT','LNG','NAME','CATEGORY'])

mymap = folium.Map(location=[df['LAT'].mean(), df['LNG'].mean()], zoom_start=12)

mCluster_ALDI = MarkerCluster(name="ALDI").add_to(mymap)
mCluster_LIDL = MarkerCluster(name="LIDL").add_to(mymap)

for row in df.itertuples():
    #print(row)
    location = row[1], row[2]
    marker = folium.Marker(location=location)
    if row[4] == 'ALDI':
        mCluster_ALDI.add_child(marker)
    elif row[4] == 'LIDL':
        mCluster_LIDL.add_child(marker)    

folium.LayerControl().add_to(mymap);

mymap
```

[image] [image]